# What happens to an adverbial/preposition phrase such as "on monday" when you remove the proposition "on"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

Does it simply continue to be an adverbial/preposition phrase? Or does it change its function and/or material?

Comment: The "on" is understood to be part of a prepositional phrase, as in "I will meet you at the meeting Monday at noon."

Comment: With certain nouns, like days of the week, the preposition can be understood. What else can you do with a day of the week, after all?

Comment: I might note that in terms of *usage*, there is a distinct difference between AmE and BritE. I use BritE and would never say "at the meeting Monday" - leaving out *on* sounds like an Americanism (like leaving out "and" in 120).

Answer (score 1):

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary the noun 'Monday' turns into the adverb 'Monday'.

***MONDAY***

ADVERB

(North American)

:On Monday.

For example:
‘I'll ring you Monday’

Comment: Do Canadians _ring_ each other on the telephone as the British do? Otherwise it's not quite North American.

Comment: Interesting to note that MW specifies this is a *North American* usage. Google Ngrams gives a sense of the [AmE/BritE difference](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=meeting+Monday%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cmeeting+Monday%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=6&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmeeting%20Monday%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmeeting%20Monday%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0).